# What is the general rule to use accusatival pronouns to refer to nouns repeatedly?

Tags: gramática, pronombres

I'm just a beginner of Spanish. An exercise of my Spanish text book asks the readers to ask questions about the bold part in the sentence:

Todo lo hacen **muy rápido**.

My answer is:

¿Cómo todo lo hacen?

The answer gives:

¿Cómo hacen todo?

I know that the "lo" in the original sentence refers to "todo", but why the "lo" is missing in the answer? I don't know when should we use assusatival pronouns to refer to the noun repeatedly. Is there a general rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not easy for me (native speaker) to distill the general rule. But, as a matter of fact:

> ¿Cómo hacen todo?

and

> ¿Cómo lo hacen?

would be correct constructions, though they would be slightly different questions. In the later, "lo", of course alludes to the thing that is being done ("todo" - direct object -  you can try replacing it by "el trabajo"), which here is left tacit; hence, this would only make sense if the previous sentence or the context had mentioned that, eg: "-Siempre hacen todo de la misma manera. -¿Cómo lo hacen?"

So, your book/teacher is right.

To say

> ¿Cómo lo hacen todo?

would be a redundant construction (see that it's a merge of the two above). Incorrect, but it might happen in casual speaking, perhaps for some emphasis.

> ¿Como todo lo hacen?

would be definitely wrong, that's never the order.

Answer (score 2):

"*¿Cómo **lo** hacen todo?*" would be as valid a question for *"Todo lo hacen muy rápido"* as the one given. Word of native speaker.

Your suggestion "*¿Cómo todo lo hacen?*" would not be in the correct order.